# Persist Local AppEngine logs to Google App Engine Logger?

Tags: google-app-engine, localhost, google-logging

I need to print the logs of appengine which is running in local machine to GCP log explorer.

Hi all,

Let's say I'm running a Appengine server locally. I can read and write data to and from datastore from GCP. But is it possible to store the local server logs in the GCP Log explorer?